# How can I optimise sending push notification in CodeIgniter PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

**Problem**
I am trying to send push notification through PHP, to both Android and iOS, but I have lots of devices to send the notification, and you can see the code that it sends the notification to all of them in a loop. It's really not optimized as my dashboard gets stuck for more than a minute due to the running loop, also somehow it is not even sending a notification to all active accounts.

Can anyone here help me out?

**Code**

```
public function insert()
{
    // Set the validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|trim');

    // If the validation worked
    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $get_post = $this->input->get_post(null,true);
        $get_post['tags'] = is_array($this->input->get_post('tags')) ? $this->input->get_post('tags') : [];

        if(count($get_post['tags']) == 0)
        {
            $_SESSION['msg_error'][] = "Tags is a required field";
            redirect('admin/newsfeed/insert');
            exit;
        }

        # File uploading configuration
        $upload_path = './uploads/newsfeeds/';
        $config['upload_path'] = $upload_path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = true;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $image = '';
        # Try to upload file now
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('image'))
        {
            # Get uploading detail here
            $upload_detail = $this->upload->data();
            $image = $upload_detail['file_name'];
        } else {
            $uploaded_file_array = (isset($_FILES['image']) and $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0 and $_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) ? $_FILES['image'] : '';
            # Show uploading error only when the file uploading attempt exist.
            if( is_array($uploaded_file_array) )
            {
                $uploading_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $_SESSION['msg_error'][] = $uploading_error;
            }
        }

        # File uploading configuration
        $upload_path = './uploads/newsfeeds/';
        $config['upload_path'] = $upload_path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
        $config['max_size'] = 51200; //KB

        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        $audio = '';
        # Try to upload file now
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('audio'))
        {
            # Get uploading detail here
            $upload_detail = $this->upload->data();
            $audio = $upload_detail['file_name'];
        }
        else
        {
            $uploaded_file_array = (isset($_FILES['audio']) and $_FILES['audio']['size'] > 0 and $_FILES['audio']['error'] == 0) ? $_FILES['audio'] : '';
            # Show uploading error only when the file uploading attempt exist.
            if( is_array($uploaded_file_array) )
            {
                $uploading_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $_SESSION['msg_error'][] = $uploading_error;
            }
        }

        $get_post['image'] = $image;
        $get_post['audio'] = $audio;


        if($id = $this->newsfeed_model->insert($get_post))
        {
            if($get_post['status'])
            {
                // send push notification to all users
                $notification = $this->newsfeed_model->get_newsfeed_by_id($id);
                $notification->notification_type = 'article';
                $notification->title = $get_post['n_title'];
                $notification->body = $get_post['n_description'];

                $query = $this->db->get_where('users', ['device_id !=' => '']);
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                    if ($row->device == 'IOS') {
                        $this->notification_model->sendPushNotificationIOS($row->device_id, $notification);
                    }
                    if ($row->device == 'ANDROID') {
                        $this->notification_model->sendPushNotificationAndroid($row->device_id, $notification);
                    }
                }
            }
            $_SESSION['msg_success'][] = 'Record added successfully...';
            if($image){
                redirect('admin/newsfeed/crop_image?id='.$id);
            } else {
                redirect('admin/newsfeed/');
            }
        }
    }

    $this->data['selected_page'] = 'newsfeed';
    $this->load->view('admin/newsfeed_add', $this->data);
}
```

**Description**
The method is adding a newsfeed, its checks for the validations, then it inserts the feed to the db, once thats done, it sends out the notification to all devices.

**Problematic Chunk**

```
if($id = $this->newsfeed_model->insert($get_post))
{
    if($get_post['status'])
    {
        // send push notification to all users
        $notification = $this->newsfeed_model->get_newsfeed_by_id($id);
        $notification->notification_type = 'article';
        $notification->title = $get_post['n_title'];
        $notification->body = $get_post['n_description'];

        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', ['device_id !=' => '']);
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            if ($row->device == 'IOS') {
                $this->notification_model->sendPushNotificationIOS($row->device_id, $notification);
            }
            if ($row->device == 'ANDROID') {
                $this->notification_model->sendPushNotificationAndroid($row->device_id, $notification);
            }
        }
    }

    $_SESSION['msg_success'][] = 'Record added successfully...';
    if($image) {
        redirect('admin/newsfeed/crop_image?id='.$id);
    } else{
        redirect('admin/newsfeed/');
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use shell scripting for this, I was stuck too in same situation then I used `shell scripting`.

Comment: It's better to get all `IOS` notification as array and send notification as batch and do this for every device type

Comment: @saddam Can you elaborate bit more? Or provide me a link to any resource?

Comment: @nima Can you elaborate bit more? Or provide me a link to any resource?

Comment: run query on `notification` table like this `select * from notification where device_type = 'IOS'`
and get all id that return to you 
than write function that send notification and get array_of_device_ids as input to send notification

Comment: there is no link to optimize your code,those are all expermients in work